# Shiny: error while including conditionalPanel for radioButtons inputs in sidebarpanel

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to include `conditionalPanel` for existing `radioButtons` input in a shiny app. Initially, the options in the `radioButtons` are not selected and when they are selected, `conditionalPanel` condition should be evaluated. I have tried by verifying for a single option, it did not work.

Code:

```
radioButtons('e_types', 
             'E types to color:', 
             list('C type'='c_type','D type'='d_type','O type'='o_type'),
             selected = NA),

             conditionalPanel(
               condition = "input.e_types == 'c_type'",
               sliderInput("breakCount", "Break Count", min=1, max=1000, value=10))
```

Comment: `conditionalPanel` should be outside `radioButtons()`. Is it a typo in the question or in the actual code?

Comment: @GGamba It is a typo, have rectified. Please suggest a way for checking if any option is selected from the available options.

Comment: @Prradep, you could just use `if(input$e_types == "choice1")` to check your selected option in server side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.e_types != null",
        sliderInput("breakCount", "Break Count", min=1, max=1000, value=10)
    )
```